# Relation between categorical operations (limits and co-limits)

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Suppose I have a diagram $B \longleftarrow A \longrightarrow C$ in a category, and I execute a push-out operation and get $B \longrightarrow D \longleftarrow C$.

If I execute a pull-back over $B \longrightarrow D \longleftarrow C$, will I reach the same diagram $B \longleftarrow A \longrightarrow C$? Why?

As another question, suppose I execute a product operation over $A$ and $B$, and get $A \longleftarrow P \longrightarrow B$, also I execute co-product operation over the same $A$ and $B$, and get $A \longrightarrow CP \longleftarrow B$.

Is $A \longleftarrow P \longrightarrow B$ pull-back of $A \longrightarrow CP \longleftarrow B$?

How can I study the relations between limits and co-limits in general? Is there any reference discussing this in a consolidated manner.

Comment: The basic relationship between limits and colimits is that a limit in $C$ corresponds to a colimit in the opposite category $C^{op}$, and vice versa. It is generally not true that pullback squares are also pushout squares or vice versa, and straightforward to find counterexamples in $\text{Set}$.

Comment: Have you even tried some examples?